# How to join table in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables.

table_A:

```
id  teachername                   schoolname
1   Alfreds Futterkiste            abc4
2   Blauer See Delikatessen        abc1
3   Maria Anders                   abc5
4   Thomas Hardy                   abc2
5   Elizabeth Lincoln              abc1
6   Victoria Ashworth              abc4
7   Patricio Simpson               abc3
8   Howard Snyder                  abc5
9   Yang Wang                      abc2
10  Janine Labrune                 abc3
```

table_B:

```
id      schoolname         branch        city
 1       abc1               xyz5         new york
 2       abc2               xyz4         london
 3       abc3               xyz3         sydney
 4       abc4               xyz1         new york
 5       abc1               xyz2         new york
 6       abc2               xyz5         sydney
 7       abc3               xyz4         londonk
 8       abc5               xyz1         london
 9       abc4               xyz2         london
 10      abc5               xyz3         sydney
```

- I want to access **"Teacher Name"** From **Table-A** based on **"School Name"** From **Table-B**
- based on user input query **"xyz4 london"**
- If user search for **"xyz4 london"** then check what **School Name** exist on Table-B
- If **"Scool Name"** exist then return **"Teachers Name"** From ***Table-A*** based on **"School Name"**

***What I am trying:*** Trying to get **"School Name"** From ***Table-B*** from user input query **"xyz4 london"**

```
// Nothing get
SELECT schoolname FROM table_B WHERE branch, city LIKE '%xyz4 london%';

// Nothing get
SELECT schoolname FROM table_B WHERE branch LIKE '%xyz4 london%' OR city LIKE '%xyz4 london%' ;


// Getting school name but no use - because this is not full query "xyz4 london"
    SELECT schoolname FROM table_B WHERE branch LIKE '%xyz4' OR city LIKE '%london%' ;
```

I want only single query to return **Teacher Name** based on ***Table-B*** **"School Name"**

Any Idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score -1):

You can search a concatenation of the fields

```
SELECT schoolname FROM table_B WHERE branch || ' ' || city LIKE '%xyz4 london%';
```

Or you can reverse the search

```
SELECT schoolname FROM table_B WHERE 'xyz4' like '%' || branch || '%' OR 'london' like '%' || city || '%' ;
```

But the clean way is to divide your input in two and to query both field independently

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am not getting what you have suggested "divide your input in two and to query both field independently". Kindly explain me if you can how to divide input query? Thanks

Comment: You can use two input box instead of 1, or split the input on space. That could be done before querying the DB